# HOW TO ADD workers dynamically in localcluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a local cluster. How can i add more workers to this local cluster using Client object.

Comment: You can give what you have done currently.

Answer (score 2):

You won't do this with the Client object but instead with Cluster.  Then use `cluster.scale(...)`:

```py
In [1]: from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

In [2]: cluster = LocalCluster()

In [3]: client = Client(cluster)

In [4]: client
Out[4]: <Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:37971' processes=12 threads=96, memory=1.62 TB>

In [5]: cluster.scale(20)

In [6]: client
Out[6]: <Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:37971' processes=20 threads=160, memory=2.70 TB>
```

You could also look at adaptive scaling: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/adaptive.html

Comment: yeah. But i don't have the cluster object saved. Can i get the cluster object.

Comment: You can probably get to it with `client.cluster.scale(...)`

Comment: it is giving error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scale'

Comment: Then you should explicitly create the cluster object